# (Ajax + PHP) My Google Map is disappearing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

I'm having troubles showing a Google Map on my index page. 
Here's how I'm currently trying:

1. Using a **GoogleMapApiV3** PHP class (http://pastebin.com/LCb3mP7f)
2. Generating my map in a PHP file (loadMap.php) using this:

`$gmap->generate();`
`echo $gmap->getGoogleMap();`

3 - Getting the map's script using AJAX (basically what's in the `echo`) then executing it using `eval()`.

Here's the content of my **refresh.js** page :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // show map and news
    refreshGUI();
});

// Update every 5 seconds
setInterval('refreshData()', 5000);
setInterval('refreshGUI()', 5000);

function refreshData() {
    $.post('index.php?js=refresh');
}
;

// Refreshes the page elements
function refreshGUI() {
    refreshNews();
    refreshMap();
} 

function refreshNews() {
    $.post('index.php?js=lastNews&lim=3', function(data) {
        var s = '';
        data = data.childNodes.item(0);
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.childNodes.length; i++) {
            data2 = data.childNodes.item(i);
            s += ('<div>' + data2.childNodes.item(1).textContent + '</div>');
            $('#newspane #news').html(s);
        }
        $('#newspane #news').html($('#newspane #news').html() + s);
    });
}

function refreshMap() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            myDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            var myScripts = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("script");
            if (myScripts.length > 0) {
                eval(myScripts[0].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
    // js=loadMap is my loadMap.php file, where I echo the map's script.
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?js=loadMap", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**My problem:** The map only shows when I manually refresh my index page using CTRL+F5. It then disappears after 5 seconds (I'm guessing it's because of `setInterval()`)

How can I fix this? What's the best way of doing this?

This whole thing has been driving me crazy, thanks in advance for any kind of help!

halpsb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is driving you mad, you are correct.

```
setInterval('refreshData()', 5000);
setInterval('refreshGUI()', 5000);
```

You are not mandating any sequence, just simultaneusly firing 3 ajax calls.

So things get mixed up.

Because you are receiving interdependant data asynchronously, and at each receiving point you assume that you have all the datasets ready in your hand which is not...

setTimeout is better than setInterval here because: setInterval will start at every 5 secs but setTimeout will start **once** each time your job is done and wait for 5 seconds, which will make your script adaptive to server response timings.

Note that I do not **know** jQuery calls so you better figure out the correct syntax.

Below, I give two example modifications of your code according to your needs:

**If you need first the data, then the news and then the map do it like this**

pseudo-code:

```
start the sequence directly with a refreshData for first render

                           send refreshData 
when async receive occurs  send refreshNews
when async receive occurs  send refreshMap
when async receive occurs  render output
after render complete      setTimeout('refreshData',5000);
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshData(); 
});


function refreshData() {
    $.post('index.php?js=refresh',
            refreshNews); // that is the part I am not so sure
}                           // I am jQuery illiterate sorry..

function refreshNews() {
    $.post('index.php?js=lastNews&lim=3', function(data) {
        var s = '';
        data = data.childNodes.item(0);
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.childNodes.length; i++) {
            data2 = data.childNodes.item(i);
            s += ('<div>' + data2.childNodes.item(1).textContent + '</div>');
            $('#newspane #news').html(s);
        }
        $('#newspane #news').html($('#newspane #news').html() + s);
    //---------------------------------------
        refreshMap();  // here add this
    //---------------------------------------
   });
}

function refreshMap() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            myDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            var myScripts = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("script");
            if (myScripts.length > 0) {
                eval(myScripts[0].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    //--------------------------------
    setTimeout(refreshData, 5000); // restart sequence in 5 seconds
    //--------------------------------
    }
    // js=loadMap is my loadMap.php file, where I echo the map's script.
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?js=loadMap", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

**If you need first the news then the map and then tha data do it like this**

pseudo-code:

```
start the sequence directly with a refreshNews for first render

                           send refreshNews
when async receive occurs  send refreshMap
when async receive occurs  send refreshData
when async receive occurs  render output
after render complete      setTimeout('refreshNews',5000);
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshNews(); 
});


function refreshData() {
    $.post('index.php?js=refresh',
        function(){
            setTimeout(refreshNews, 5000); // restart sequence in 5
        }
    ); // that is the part I am not so sure
}      // I am jQuery illiterate sorry..

function refreshNews() {
    $.post('index.php?js=lastNews&lim=3', function(data) {
        var s = '';
        data = data.childNodes.item(0);
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.childNodes.length; i++) {
            data2 = data.childNodes.item(i);
            s += ('<div>' + data2.childNodes.item(1).textContent + '</div>');
            $('#newspane #news').html(s);
        }
        $('#newspane #news').html($('#newspane #news').html() + s);
    //---------------------------------------
        refreshMap();  // here add this
    //---------------------------------------
   });
}

function refreshMap() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            myDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            var myScripts = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("script");
            if (myScripts.length > 0) {
                eval(myScripts[0].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    //--------------------------------
        refreshData(); // here add this
    //--------------------------------
    }
    // js=loadMap is my loadMap.php file, where I echo the map's script.
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?js=loadMap", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

I hope this is clear enough to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe that I now understand what the problem is, however I am not exactly sure what you meant in your pseudo-code. Do I need to remove both `setInterval()`, separate the async code from the `refreshMap()` and then call `refreshMap()` and `refreshNews()` in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){}` ?

Comment: I added extra info to my answer.